How can i import xls files in python?
The xls file from excel 97-2003 like xml file.
I tried with pandas,xlrd, openpyxl and other ways. I couldn't import in python. How can i deal with?
Code=
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('KONKA_1284314_2023_4.xls')

Error=
XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<html xm'

The file example which i work on it.
text
enter image description here
Thanks.
try to import python a xls file.

Those files appear to be corrupted or not in correct format.

Right.  You have downloaded an HTML page, not an Excel spreadsheet.  Perhaps the site required logging in before download.

actually ı opened via excel and save as .xlsx excel then file worked. But not work as original xls

As @Tim Roberts stated, what is downloaded is a html file with an '.xls' extension so these apps cannot open it. But as you see Excel can open a html file so it can then be saved as '.xls' or '.xlsx'.

Just because it has a .xls extension does not mean it is an Excel file.  Excel might be able to read some HTML files, but xlrd cannot.

Agree with the comments above. The file that you've downloaded is not an Excel file, i.e. .xls file.
